# system does not beep while taking screenshots in scrot

Tags: scrot-command

I am trying to learn `scrot` utility and there is an option `-z` or `--silent` to prevent beeping. But my system is not beeping  at all and so I am unable to test this `-z` option. I have installed the `beep` utility in my system.

Comment: I use Lubuntu, which comes with scrot. It does not beep for me, and I am happy with that. The file is created in the directory from where you start the program. I often use the options -s and -sb to take a screenshot of a window (without and with the header and border).

Comment: I too could never get `beep` to work on Lubuntu. Instead, I chain a sound from `/usr/share/sounds`. So, for example, I could use `scrot && mplayer -really-quiet /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter.oga`. But it looks like you *don't* want the beep so where's the problem?

Comment: No, I want beep, at least for once, I want to test this command option. So, can you tell how will beep work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with lubuntu per-se, but at least on my version of ubuntu, you need to enable pcspkr module: `modprobe pcspkr` - you may need to do that with `sudo` and may want to add it to `/etc/modules`

then again, i may be completely off the mark for your use case. good luck.

Comment: (if you hear a beep when you run `beep`, then your modules should be fine and you can disregard this answer)

Comment: Heads up, extra data point: On my system, `scrot file.png` beeps but `beep` does not. So `beep` and `scrot` may not be doing the same thing. (And I don't care about beep not beeping. I was looking for the `-z` option to silence the sound from `scrot` and that works.)